# Angular, @NgModule diferencia entre usar declarations y entryComponents

Tags: angular

En `Angular` **@NgModule** ¿Cual es exactamente la diferencia entre usar **"declarations"** y **"entryComponents"**? solo sé que en ambos podemos incluir componentes de otros módulos, pero exactamente cuando debo usar el **"entryComponents"** o que ventajas da al usar.

Answer (score 0):

El array `entryComponents` se utiliza para definir solo componentes que no se encuentran representados o llamados bajo un etiqueta en el html, estos se crean dinámicamente con ComponentFactoryResolver y Angular necesita esta pista para encontrarlos y compilarlos. Todos los demás componentes tan solo deben aparecer en un array de declaraciones o `declarations`.